# neo4j java rest binding api not returning from getNodeAutoIndexer

Tags: java, neo4j

I have an application which uses neo4j embedded database. Now, I want to migrate to neo4j server as I need to integrate this application with a web app (using servlets, tomcat).

I want to change the code minimally, So I thought of using java-rest-binding api of neo4j. But I am stuck at getting the auto node index. The method `getAutoNodeIndexer` doesn't return. In **messages.log** of the database, It shows

```
[o.n.k.EmbeddedGraphDatabase]: GC Monitor: Application threads blocked for an additional 254ms [total block time: 2.678s]
```

I have no idea how to solve this.

I have set the appropriate properties in the **neo4j.properties**, which are

```
node_auto_indexing=true
node_keys_indexable=primaryKey
relationship_auto_indexing=true
relationship_keys_indexable=X-->Y
```

And this is what my code looks like:

```
graphDb = new RestGraphDatabase("http://localhost:7474/db/data/"); 
ReadableIndex<Node> autoNodeIndex =     graphDb.index().getNodeAutoIndexer().getAutoIndex();
ReadableRelationshipIndex autoRelIndex = graphDb.index().getRelationshipAutoIndexer().getAutoIndex();
```

Comment: This is wrong `relationship_keys_indexable=X-->Y` it should be something like: relationship_keys_indexable=relProperty1,relProperty2

Comment: I'm not sure that method was actually implemented.

Comment: But you don't have any transaction around it? Can you share the full code that you run?

Comment: What do you want to do with the auto-indexer? Can you just try a cypher statement like `start n=node:node_auto_index(primaryKey="value") return n`

Comment: and can you do just a curl command: `curl http://localhost:7474/db/data/`

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's a lot of garbage collection going on. Run your app with a bigger heap (e.g. -Xmx1g) and see what happens.

EDIT:

Also, `relationship_keys_indexable=X-->Y` seems strange. I'd expect a property name there. What happens if you remove this property or enter a valid value?

To state the [official documentation](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-configurable-auto-indexes.html):

> The node_keys_indexable key allows you to specify a comma-separated
>   list of node property keys to be indexed. The
>   relationship_keys_indexable does the same for relationship property
>   keys.

Comment: Tried it. Didn't help. But now there are no logs of blocking application thread in messages.log.

Comment: I just enabled http logging too. Don't see anything there. Is it possible my app is not able to connect to neo4j server?

Comment: I don't expect so. You should have some kind of `ConnectException` when your server can't be found. See edited answer for another clue.

Comment: Removing the property or adding the valid values didn't help either.